# passing Jenkins env variables between stages on different agents

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've looked at this [Pass Artifact or String to upstream job in Jenkins Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39730193/pass-artifact-or-string-to-upstream-job-in-jenkins-pipeline) and this [Pass variables between Jenkins stages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47462500/pass-variables-between-jenkins-stages) and this [How do I pass variables between stages in a declarative Jenkins pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44099851/how-do-i-pass-variables-between-stages-in-a-declarative-jenkins-pipeline), but none of these questions seem to deal with my specific problem.

Basically I have a pipeline consisting of multiple stages, each run in its own agent.

In the first stage I run a shell script. Here two variables are generated. I would like to use these variables in the next stage. The methods I've seen so far seem to only work when passing variables within the same agent.

```
pipeline {

    stages {
        stage("stage 1") {
           agent {
                docker {
                    image 'my_image:latest'
                }
            }
            steps {
               sh ("""
                export VAR1=foo
                export VAR2=bar
             """)                
            }
        }

       stage("stage 2") {
           agent {
                docker {
                    image 'my_other_image:latest'
                }
            }
            steps {
               sh ("echo "$VAR1 $VAR2")
               //expecting to see "foo bar" printed here             
            }
        }
```

Comment: Answer to global environment variable setting is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62880159/is-it-possible-to-set-the-value-of-an-environmental-variable-on-an-agent-node-fr/62882438#62882438

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64572833/2047614) for information on what happens to your variables.